# Profiling node.js in IntelliJ WebStorm

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, webstorm

The IntelliJ [V8 CPU and Memory Profiling](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/v8-cpu-and-memory-profiling.html) page describes how to run V8. I get the following when selecting Run from within WebStorm:

```
   /usr/local/bin/node . --prof --logfile=v8-3-14-16_10-52-54-AM-0.log --log-timer-events
   Web server listening at: http://0.0.0.0:3000
   Browse your REST API at http://0.0.0.0:3000/explorer
```

Which all seems fine. Then when I select stop ... I get

```
   Process finished with exit code 130
```

and WebStorm complains

```
  "No V8 log files found".
```

Is there some step that I am missing to get to the log files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.js profiler requires application main file being passed AFTER profiler arguments, and you are passing '.' BEFORE. Please try changing your command line accordingly (`/usr/local/bin/node --prof --logfile=v8-3-14-16_10-52-54-AM-0.log --log-timer-events .`, or `/usr/local/bin/node --prof --logfile=v8-3-14-16_10-52-54-AM-0.log --log-timer-events index.js`, or whatever your server main file name is)

[image]